# ImportError at /complete/facebook/ No module named 'social_core.contrib'

Tags: django, importerror, python-social-auth

I started using python-social-auth with Django 1.8 / Python 3.5 a couple weeks ago and was getting ready to work on getting user profile data beyond user name and email from Facebook and google when I noticed the "Deprecation notice - 03-12-2016" at https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth.

I uninstalled python-social-auth and installed social-auth-core and social-auth-app-django in it's place, as I understood was recommended at the page referenced above. I followed the "Migrating from python-social-auth to split social" steps at https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/MIGRATING_TO_SOCIAL.md, and now I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError at /complete/facebook/ No module named 'social_core.contrib'

### Could someone advise me on how to get this solved?

The traceback:

```
    ImportError at /login/facebook/
    No module named 'social_core.contrib'
    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://example.com:8000/login/facebook/?next=/
    Django Version:     1.8
    Exception Type:     ImportError
    Exception Value:    
    No module named 'social_core.contrib'
    Exception Location:     C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py in import_module, line 52
    Python Executable:  C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version:     3.5.1
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\DLLs',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\lib',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\Scripts',
     'c:\\program files (x86)\\python35-32\\Lib',
     'c:\\program files (x86)\\python35-32\\DLLs',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01',
     'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Sun, 11 Dec 2016 01:05:05 -0600
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                                            response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
                                response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py in wrapper
                                                                       backend, uri)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py in load_backend
                            Backend = get_backend(BACKENDS, name)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\utils.py in get_backend
                                load_backends(backends, force_load=True)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\utils.py in load_backends
                                    backend = module_member(auth_backend)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py in module_member
                            module = import_module(mod)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
        C:\__files\DJANGO\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py in import_module
                            __import__(name)
             ...
        ▶ Local vars
    Request information
    GET
    Variable    Value
    next    
    '/'
    POST
    No POST data
    FILES
    No FILES data
    COOKIES
    Variable    Value
    sessionid   
    '8pv390k2ombcrrihkqzaccb7y2x1r6hd'
    csrftoken   
    '5W0PrAk5uR2T7HlttjyJm4fntXZwqZQ3'
    META
    Variable    Value
    HTTP_DNT    
    '1'
    wsgi.multiprocess   
    False
    SYSTEMROOT  
    'C:\\Windows'
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH   
    ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python35-32\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Python35-32\\;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program '
     'Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS '
     'Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine '
     'Components\\IPT;C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.15;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Utilities\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL '
     'Utilities\\Doctrine extensions for PHP\\;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;C:\\Program Files\\gettext-iconv\\bin;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Ruby22\\bin;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\usr\\bin')
    HTTP_ACCEPT     
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    PATH    
    ('C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Python35-32\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Python35-32\\;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program '
     'Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS '
     'Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine '
     'Components\\IPT;C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.15;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Utilities\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL '
     'Utilities\\Doctrine extensions for PHP\\;C:\\Program Files '
     '(x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;C:\\Program Files\\gettext-iconv\\bin;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Ruby22\\bin;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\usr\\bin')
    SESSIONNAME     
    'Console'
    SERVER_PORT     
    '8000'
    WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE     
    'C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log'
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    
    'Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel'
    HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
    '1'
    CONTENT_LENGTH  
    ''
    COMMONPROGRAMFILES  
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
    PATHEXT     
    '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.RB;.RBW'
    COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)     
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
    wsgi.version    
    (1, 0)
    TEMP    
    'C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    
    '4'
    HOMEPATH    
    '\\Users\\U1'
    PROGRAMW6432    
    'C:\\Program Files'
    QUERY_STRING    
    'next=/'
    WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS   
    '3'
    REMOTE_HOST     
    ''
    LOGONSERVER     
    '\\\\I11'
    wsgi.multithread    
    True
    ACTEL_FOR_ALTIUM_OVERRIDE   
    ' '
    USERNAME    
    'U1'
    PUBLIC  
    'C:\\Users\\Public'
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT     
    '$P$G'
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
    'gzip, deflate'
    CONTENT_TYPE    
    'text/plain'
    CSRF_COOKIE     
    '5W0PrAk5uR2T7HlttjyJm4fntXZwqZQ3'
    SERVER_NAME     
    'lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com'
    SERVER_PROTOCOL     
    'HTTP/1.1'
    DJANGO_ENV  
    'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\django_env'
    HTTP_USER_AGENT     
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK    
    'NO'
    HTTP_REFERER    
    'http://example.com:8000/'
    wsgi.run_once   
    False
    COMMONPROGRAMW6432  
    'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
    HTTP_CONNECTION     
    'keep-alive'
    wsgi.input  
    
    TMP     
    'C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
    PSMODULEPATH    
    'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\'
    SYSTEMDRIVE     
    'C:'
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
    'en,es;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3'
    PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN    
    'C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.15\\php.exe'
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
    'central_config.settings'
    APPDATA     
    'C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Roaming'
    PROGRAMDATA     
    'C:\\ProgramData'
    PROGRAMFILES    
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
    ALLUSERSPROFILE     
    'C:\\ProgramData'
    WINDIR  
    'C:\\Windows'
    VIRTUAL_ENV     
    'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01'
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  
    'x86'
    SERVER_SOFTWARE     
    'WSGIServer/0.2'
    USERDOMAIN  
    'I11'
    REQUEST_METHOD  
    'GET'
    PROMPT  
    '(DJANGO_TRAIN_01) $P$G'
    ALTERA_FOR_ALTIUM_OVERRIDE  
    ' '
    USERPROFILE     
    'C:\\Users\\U1'
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432  
    'AMD64'
    REMOTE_ADDR     
    '127.0.0.1'
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL     
    '6'
    PROGRAMFILES(X86)   
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
    COMSPEC     
    'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
    SCRIPT_NAME     
    ''
    HTTP_HOST   
    'example.com:8000'
    PROCESSOR_REVISION  
    '3c03'
    wsgi.errors     
    ' mode='w' encoding='cp437'>
    HTTP_COOKIE     
    ('csrftoken=5W0PrAk5uR2T7HlttjyJm4fntXZwqZQ3; '
     'sessionid=8pv390k2ombcrrihkqzaccb7y2x1r6hd')
    wsgi.file_wrapper   
    ''
    XPYTHONPATH     
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python35-32\\Lib\\site-packages'
    PATH_INFO   
    '/login/facebook/'
    JAVA_HOME   
    'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_66'
    COMPUTERNAME    
    'I11'
    RUN_MAIN    
    'true'
    OS  
    'Windows_NT'
    wsgi.url_scheme     
    'http'
    LOCALAPPDATA    
    'C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local'
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
    'CGI/1.1'
    HOMEDRIVE   
    'C:'
    Settings
    sing settings module central_config.settings
    etting  Value
    RISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK     
    'bootstrap3'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET     
    '********************'
    LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
    '/'
    CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
    600
    TEMPLATES   
    [{'APP_DIRS': True,
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': ['C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src\\templates'],
      'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.media',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.static',
                                         'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                                         'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                         'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                                         'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                                         'central_config.context_processors.one.locale',
                                         'central_config.context_processors.one.equis']}}]
    PASSWORD_HASHERS    
    '********************'
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
    ('%Y-%m-%d',
     '%m/%d/%Y',
     '%m/%d/%y',
     '%b %d %Y',
     '%b %d, %Y',
     '%d %b %Y',
     '%d %b, %Y',
     '%B %d %Y',
     '%B %d, %Y',
     '%d %B %Y',
     '%d %B, %Y')
    SESSION_COOKIE_PATH     
    '/'
    ADMINS  
    ()
    INTERNAL_IPS    
    ()
    DEBUG   
    True
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT     
    False
    MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
    'F j'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY    
    '********************'
    TEST_RUNNER     
    'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
    MESSAGE_STORAGE     
    'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
    None
    SESSION_SERIALIZER  
    'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
    STATIC_ROOT     
    'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\static_in_env\\static_root'
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS     
    ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.template.context_processors.debug',
     'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
     'django.template.context_processors.media',
     'django.template.context_processors.static',
     'django.template.context_processors.tz',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
    MANAGERS    
    ()
    CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
    'default'
    EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
    None
    TIME_FORMAT     
    'P'
    APPEND_SLASH    
    True
    SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
    []
    SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
    'm/d/Y P'
    DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
    ''
    CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
    '/'
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
    ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
    STATICFILES_STORAGE     
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
    EMAIL_BACKEND   
    'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    FILE_CHARSET    
    'utf-8'
    ALLOWED_HOSTS   
    []
    LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
    None
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
    False
    STATIC_URL  
    '/static/'
    SECURE_SSL_HOST     
    None
    STATICFILES_FINDERS     
    ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS     
    0
    LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
    'django_language'
    FIXTURE_DIRS    
    ()
    TEMPLATE_DIRS   
    ()
    CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX     
    '********************'
    USE_I18N    
    True
    SESSION_ENGINE  
    'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER     
    None
    TIME_ZONE   
    'UTC'
    LANGUAGES_BIDI  
    ('he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur')
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE     
    True
    PREPEND_WWW     
    False
    DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
    '.'
    CACHES  
    {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
    DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
    False
    FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
    0
    FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
    None
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
    False
    THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
    ','
    CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
    'csrftoken'
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
    'webmaster@localhost'
    DATETIME_FORMAT     
    'N j, Y, P'
    DATABASES   
    {'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
                 'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
                 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
                 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                 'HOST': '',
                 'NAME': 'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src\\db.sqlite3',
                 'OPTIONS': {},
                 'PASSWORD': '********************',
                 'PORT': '',
                 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                          'COLLATION': None,
                          'MIRROR': None,
                          'NAME': None},
                 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
                 'USER': ''}}
    SESSION_FILE_PATH   
    None
    CRISPY_FAIL_SILENTLY    
    False
    X_FRAME_OPTIONS     
    'SAMEORIGIN'
    CSRF_COOKIE_AGE     
    31449600
    LOCALE_PATHS    
    ('C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src\\locale',)
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
    'text/html'
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
    False
    ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
    ()
    LOGGING_CONFIG  
    'logging.config.dictConfig'
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME     
    'sessionid'
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF     
    False
    SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY     
    '********************'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET    
    '********************'
    LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE     
    None
    DEFAULT_CHARSET     
    'utf-8'
    EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
    None
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
    '/'
    DATE_FORMAT     
    'N j, Y'
    FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     
    2621440
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD     
    '********************'
    DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
    ''
    CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
    False
    TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
    []
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
    '********************'
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS     
    ('social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
     'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
     'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
     'social_core.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    ROOT_URLCONF    
    'central_config.urls'
    USE_TZ  
    True
    USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
    True
    FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
    ('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
     'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
    CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
    None
    EMAIL_HOST  
    'smtp.gmail.com'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET  
    '********************'
    SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
    True
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
    False
    DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
    'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
    SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
    []
    IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
    ()
    ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS     
    7
    STATICFILES_DIRS    
    ('C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src\\static_in_pro\\our_static',)
    SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
    180
    CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
    'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
    FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
    None
    EMAIL_USE_SSL   
    False
    SERVER_EMAIL    
    'root@localhost'
    FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS     
    None
    YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
    'F Y'
    INSTALLED_APPS  
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.humanize',
     'social_django',
     'crispy_forms',
     'registration',
     'central',
     'filehand',
     'cronosales',
     'devtests']
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
    False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
    False
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY   
    '********************'
    EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
    '********************'
    SECRET_KEY  
    '********************'
    USE_ETAGS   
    False
    LOGGING     
    {}
    MIGRATION_MODULES   
    {}
    DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
    ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
     '%Y-%m-%d',
     '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
     '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
     '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
     '%m/%d/%Y',
     '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
     '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
     '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
     '%m/%d/%y')
    MEDIA_URL   
    '/media/'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER     
    'xoselor@gmail.com'
    SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS     
    'default'
    EMAIL_PORT  
    587
    PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS     
    '********************'
    NUMBER_GROUPING     
    0
    LANGUAGE_CODE   
    'es'
    LOGIN_URL   
    '/accounts/login/'
    SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
    'm/d/Y'
    ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
    {}
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
    'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
    REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN     
    True
    TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
    ''
    AUTH_USER_MODEL     
    'auth.User'
    SIGNING_BACKEND     
    'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
    DATABASE_ROUTERS    
    []
    USE_L10N    
    True
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY     
    True
    WSGI_APPLICATION    
    'central_config.wsgi.application'
    EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
    '[Django] '
    EMAIL_USE_TLS   
    True
    FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
    None
    SITE_ID     
    1
    LANGUAGES   
    [('es', .__proxy__ object at 0x02CACC90>),
     ('en', .__proxy__ object at 0x02CACC70>),
     ('de', .__proxy__ object at 0x02CACCD0>)]
    DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
    ()
    FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
    None
    MEDIA_ROOT  
    'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\static_in_env\\media_root'
    SETTINGS_MODULE     
    'central_config.settings'
    LOGOUT_URL  
    '/accounts/logout/'
    TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
    ('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M')
    BASE_DIR    
    'C:\\__files\\DJANGO\\DJANGO_TRAIN_01\\src'
    You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Comment: Could you add the full traceback?

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM.

Comment: In my settings for python-social-auth, I had AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
   'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
) For social-auth-core, I changed that to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
   'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
   'social_core.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
) The last line, which I made up, was the problem.

Comment: Took it out and now my Facebook, Google and Twitter logins work as they did before I uninstalled python-social-auth and installed social-auth-core and social-auth-app-django in it's place.

Comment: Great, I had the impression it was going to be something like that. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for following up.